# Xwiki Access Rights (AppWithinMinutes)

Tags: xwiki

I apologize if the question has already been asked. I made an application with “AppWithinMinutes” in Xwiki. In this application I get user information (eg name, age, etc.)
My application will be 100-150 users.
Each user will enter information.

I have studied these connections:
https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Access%20Rights/
https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Access%20Rights/Permission%20types/
My English is a little bad. :slight_smile:

In my application every user just want to see their own information
For example, the AA user only sees the information he enters.

I don’t want you to see the information that other users have entered.(for example, CC,DD,EE users…etc)
How do I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not very simple. What you can do is write an event listener: https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Tutorials/WritingEventListenerTutorial/ which listens for `DocumentCreatingEvent` and attach a "view" rights object to the new document if it has an object of the class of your App, loosely similar to:  https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-oldcore/src/main/java/com/xpn/xwiki/XWiki.java#L3924

Comment: thanks i tried other solution way